# Python - prevent from opening file in particular format

Tags: python

is there any way im Python to prevent from opening a file by user in i.e. .pdf format during code execution?
My code is opening/saving multiple files in a loop and opening a new one may lead to an error.
The OS is Windows.
Thanks

Comment: We need to see your code to know how to help you

Answer (score 1):

Make it a function for opening file

Check the extension if extension is allowed then

read

else return or can raise custom exception

```
from os import path

def openfile(filename):
    dont_read_extensions = [".pdf", ".jpg"]
    extension = path.splitext(filename)[1]
    if extension in dont_read_extensions:
        return #or you can raise custom exception
    else:
        with open(filename,"r") as f:
             #do file operations
             return # you can return with result
```